# Swagger UI: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource on deployed application

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi

I've just deployed my application (Spring Boot + Vaadin) to a free hosting (alwaysdata.com). Everything seems to be working really good so far, but the Swagger UI.

I can't make any call to my API through the Swagger UI and I'll always get the same response:

```
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

For example, there's a curl command:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://myapp.alwaysdata.net/api/auth/logout' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -d ''
```

This returns the mentioned-before error message. What's going on here?

**EDIT**: I've just used Microsoft Edge to make the same request and have been granted with a different response.

```
Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

* CORS
* Network Failure
* URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

My objective now is to make the curl command send https requests.

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved based on my update in the original post. Making requests with `HTTPS` protocol instead of `HTTP` did the job.